# HowTo manually configure typings in asp.net core app

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, typescript-typings, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I'm migrating our app from **mvc 5** to **asp.net** core 2 (visual studio 2017.3).

In the old world we had all the typings in a folder Scripts\typings\ (for `example Scripts\typings\jquery\jquery.d.ts`)

and of course that's not working anymore in asp.net core. 
I've googled and found some posts that suggest to install the typings with **npm**. However npm is blocked and i can't install anything from there.

Is there a way to manually configure the typings?

**UPDATE**

I found out that in myapp.ts i need to add a reference to the specific typing

```
/// <reference path="somewhere/typings/jquery.d.ts" />
```

that would solve the problem. However I don't think that this is very handy, as i need jquery in all my ts files. Is there a way to add somehow do the same globally?

Comment: Do you use `tsconfig`? If so, you can set `typeRoots` compiler option.

Comment: @AlekseyL. tsconfig did the trick. if you post it as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set *typeRoots* compiler option in [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) file (add it if not yet included in your project).

Edited by gsharp:

that's how my `tsconfig.json` looks like to get my my project working. Not sure if this is the best way to configure. But it does what I expect :-)

[image]

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./Typings/**"

    ] 
  }
}
```